# How to do full outer join. Not getting expected results

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to display all the seat labels with their respective rowid and columnid and additional ticket code from ticket_items to show if tickets are bought or else null. From my understanding, outer join should do my job, but its not.

The problem is as below,
1) In TICKET_ITEMS I only have 2 tickets bought with SEATNO "B1"(ROWID:1 COLID:1 )and "C2"(ROWID:2 COLID:2).

2) It is showing all the seats but with wrong ticket code. if none it should show null (full outer join)

**THEATHER**

[image: THEATHER]

**SHOWTIMES**

[image: THEATHER]

**TICKET_ITEMS**

[image: THEATHER]

**SEAT**

[image: SEAT]

**This is my query**

```
SELECT 
  SHOWTIMES.ID AS SHOWTIMESID,
  SHOWTIMES.THEATREID,
  THEATRES.THEATRENAME,
  THEATRES.NUMOFROWS,
  THEATRES.NUMOFCOLS,
  SEAT.SEATNO AS SEATLABEL,
  SEAT.ROWID,
  SEAT.COLUMNID,
  TICKET_ITEMS.SEATNO,
  TICKET_ITEMS.TICKETCODE
FROM
  SEAT  RIGHT OUTER JOIN THEATRES ON SEAT.ROOMID = THEATRES.ID
  RIGHT OUTER JOIN SHOWTIMES ON SHOWTIMES.THEATREID = THEATRES.ID
  RIGHT OUTER JOIN TICKET_ITEMS ON TICKET_ITEMS.SHOWTIMESID = SHOWTIMES.ID
WHERE
  SHOWTIMES.ID = 1
;
```

**My query results**

[image: THEATHER]

Comment: I think based on what you expected your join is not consistent (All theatre ID 1 will join to show times,All the rows in Seats have the same room)  , please provide your expected results.

Comment: @Avi As described in question, I wanted to all the seats (rowid and columnid) for that showtime. So isnt it correct to join showtimes with teathre id?

Comment: @Parfait I have corrected my mistake. I have updated image with code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of Right outer join, I think you may need left outer join. Instead of including SHOWTIMES.ID = 1 in where condition, add in and condition while doing join. This will make sure that you are not losing any records from Seats table, and get null or not null values as long as it is matching based on the joins.  Also, add another condition in the last join with seats so that you get the records only when seat is valid.

```
SELECT 
SHOWTIMES.ID AS SHOWTIMESID,
SHOWTIMES.THEATREID,
THEATRES.THEATRENAME,
THEATRES.NUMOFROWS,
THEATRES.NUMOFCOLS,
SEAT.SEATNO AS SEATLABEL,
SEAT.ROWID,
SEAT.COLUMNID,
TICKET_ITEMS.SEATNO,
TICKET_ITEMS.TICKETCODE
FROM
SEAT  left  OUTER JOIN THEATRES ON SEAT.ROOMID = THEATRES.ID
left OUTER JOIN SHOWTIMES ON SHOWTIMES.THEATREID = THEATRES.ID and SHOWTIMES.ID = 1
left OUTER JOIN TICKET_ITEMS ON TICKET_ITEMS.SHOWTIMESID = SHOWTIMES.ID and  TICKET_ITEMS.SEATNO = SEAT.SEATNO;
```